# iPhone orientation - two boxes

Tags: iphone, orientation

My iPhone app has two boxes with content. When user switch the orientation of a phone boxes change the position like this:

Portrait

```
|---------|
| BUTTON1 |
| BUTTON2 |
|---------|
|         |
| BUTTON3 |
| BUTTON4 |
|         |
|---------|
```

Landscape

```
|---------|---------------|
| BUTTON1 |    BUTTON3    |
| BUTTON2 |    BUTTON4    |
|---------|---------------|
```

What is the right way to go? Two XIBs, other tricks? Should I resize elements manually in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,125,125);
    }else{
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20,20,125,125);
    }
}
```

Of course you'll have to use your own dimensions in the CGRectMake box, but other than that, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in your view controller:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

To adjust the boxes'/views' frames. I believe they will be animated automatically.

Check the docs for more info.

Comment: hum... ok this is only the function that is called when the rotation starts. The question is how to resize boxes. This boxes have content like buttons, other elements.